# :seconds to :hours in Laravel Throttle?

Tags: php, laravel

In my

`resources/lang/en/auth.php`

I have this

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used during authentication for various
| message that we need to display to the user. You are free to modify
| these language lines according to your application's requirements.
|
*/

'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',

];
```

Is there a way to edit the throttle `:seconds` to an hour?

the error message on the front would be something like this

`Too many login attempts. Please try again in 2 hour(s).`

Answer (score 3):

By default, the throttle login trait only give `minutes` and `seconds`, if you want to add hours just override `sendLockoutResponse` method from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins` like below(in LoginController that use `AuthenticatesUsers` trait ):

```
/**
 * Redirect the user after determining they are locked out.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
{
    $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
        $this->throttleKey($request)
    );

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.throttle', [
            'seconds' => $seconds,
            'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
            'hours' => ceil($seconds / 60 / 60),
        ])],
    ])->status(Response::HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
}
```

Now you can add  hours throttles like below:

```
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :hours hour(s).',
```